# How to write view.yml of php_symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony version 1.4.1

Source I want to realize

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

I wrote view.yml(apps/masao/config/view.yml)

```
javascripts:    [//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js]
```

This is the result.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/masao//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

Since this site has both `http` and`https` possibilities, I want to write `src = "// ..."`

Comment: apparently that ancient version of symfony doesn't know about the wonderful and historically non-url `//` prefix that is trending now (and which is probably interpreted as a relative path, and is then put under the project prefix "masao"). have you tried just using `https://` instead?

Comment: side-question, why would you ever want http?

Comment: Some of the systems already running use http.